# Access Self Class Constants

Tags: php, class, constants

How can I access class constants within a function that is defined inside that class?

```
class Test{

    const STATUS_ENABLED = 'Enabled';
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 'Disabled';

    public function someMethod(){
        //how can I access ALL the constants here let's say in a form of array
    }

}
```

I don't mean to access each constant but rather access ALL the constants in a form of array. I saw something like:

```
<?php
class Profile {
    const LABEL_FIRST_NAME = "First Name";
    const LABEL_LAST_NAME = "Last Name";
    const LABEL_COMPANY_NAME = "Company";
}


$refl = new ReflectionClass('Profile');
print_r($refl->getConstants());
```

But what if I want to access ALL the list of constants inside that class?

Comment: OK, you've edited your question now that a couple of us have mentioned Reflection's getConstants() method to say that you're using getConstants() already.... so explain what problem you're having with it because it looks like it does exactly what you're asking for - [Demo](http://3v4l.org/SrnfX).

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all the defined constants for a class, you'll need to use Reflection:

The [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) object has a [getConstants()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php) method

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collect all the constants as an array, you *could* use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php):

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass("classNameGoesHere");
$reflection->getConstants();
```

However, this would be very slow and mostly pointless. What would be a much better idea, is to simply declare all of the constants in another array, which you then use:

```
class Test{

    const STATUS_ENABLED = 'Enabled';
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 'Disabled';

    $states = array(
      self::STATUS_ENABLED,
      self::STATUS_DISABLED,

}
```

This has the added advantage that it'll keep working if you add more constants. There's no reason to assume all of a class' constants are related in any way, unless you explicitly make it so by defining the relation as an array.